# Is there any USB terminals out there

Tags: windows, usb

I'm looking for a USB terminal that act like HyperTerminal or Putty in Windows. I'm developing a C# software that controls a USB device.
and I'm intending to use WinUSB, because my device won't fit in any of the device classes.

So while I'm debugging, I want a software to enter VID and PID in it, and then send and receive data to and from the device..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such thing.  USB communication is much richer than a standard terminal interface.  Unlike a terminal, you can have multiple interfaces, endpoints, and styles of transfers.  There are tools to see what's happening on the bus, such as [USBlyzer](http://www.usblyzer.com/)... but I don't know of anything that provides an interface to inject requests.  I think there's always a concern some other driver on the system is handling the device, and this kind of capability would undermine the driver.  I believe nowadays, you can do quite a bit in user mode.  You may want to checkout [#usblib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpusblib/).  It may have some handy things to get you a bit closer to what you want.